# `\input`ting contents of a file into a `hyperref`'s `pdfkeywords`

Tags: hyperref, input, revision-control, git

I use git to manage the development of my LaTeX documents, and I have a [makefile](https://github.com/jrsmith3/latex_template) I use to build a PDF from the LaTeX source. For the sake of provenance, I would like to embed the most recent git commit hash into the metadata of the resulting PDF. In that way I can send out PDFs and have a fighting chance of figuring out whence they came.

My approach is to have some code in the makefile which stores the current commit hash in a temporary file, then read the contents of that file into the `pdfkeywords` field of the `hyperref` package using the `\input` directive like so:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={A method for embedding git hash into PDF metadata},
    pdfauthor={Joshua R. Smith},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={\input{contains_git_hash.txt}},
    pdfcreator={pdfTeX}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Git should play well with \LaTeX}
But does it?

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the above code simply embeds the string "contains_git_hash.txt" in the "Keyword" metadata field of the resulting PDF instead of the contents of the file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Why not use [`gitinfo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo)?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome!

With the caveat that I've never used [gitinfo](http://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo), it looks like I would have to add a post-commit or post-checkout hook to all of my LaTeX git repos. Adding such hooks seems like overkill to me; I really want to restrict the scope of the solution to the LaTeX file and makefile without having to modify the git repo. Heiko's solution meets that requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use package `catchfile` to store the contents of a file in a macro:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\CatchFileDef{\GitHash}{contains_git_hash.txt}{}
\makeatletter
\trim@spaces@in\GitHash
\makeatother

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={A method for embedding git hash into PDF metadata},
    pdfauthor={Joshua R. Smith},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={\GitHash},
    pdfcreator={pdfTeX}
}

\begin{document}

\title{...}
\maketitle

\section{Git should play well with \LaTeX}
But does it?

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- Package `trimspaces` is used to remove the last space. If the file does only contain one line, the final space can also be removed by `\endlinechar=-1`:

  ```
  \CatchFileDef{\GitHash}{contains_git_hash.txt}{\endlinechar=-1\relax}
  ```

Comment: Can you explain why the `input` command doesn't work? Does it have to do with the order in which LaTeX executes various statements?

Comment: @joshua.r.smith: LaTeX's `\input` is not expandable (file lookup, handling non-existent files, ...). And the expandable original `\input` primitive, saved as `\@@input` in LaTeX would cause the error `! File ended while scanning definition of \@pdfkeywords.`